Generating task "g++ build active file"
Trying to build and debug simple main.cpp file in Visual Studio Code in dev Container. I have automatically configured launch.json file. But how to generate task that builds binary before run?
I execute command Tasks: Configure Task and it provides several templates that not fit my needs:

Hot to ask VSCode to create task that builds my code with g++?
I'm expecting to get task g++ build active file :
   {
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "g++ build active file",
        "command": "/bin/g++",
        "args": [
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "/bin"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": "build"
    }

Current launch.json:
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "enter program name, for example ${workspaceFolder}/a.out",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                    "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }


    ]
}


do you have the C/C++ extension installed for the container? what extensions have you installed for the container?

I have C/C++, C/C++ Extension pack, CMake

One should get generated automatically for the compiler you select when you click the run button in the action bar at the top right of the workbench. Quoting the docs:

You are only prompted to choose a compiler the first time you run helloworld.cpp. This compiler becomes "default" compiler set in your tasks.json file.

It won't look exactly like the one you've shown, but it'll be a nice basic one that you can edit to your liking.
Note that if you just want to use one of those auto-detected build tasks as a preLaunchTask, you can just reference it by name in your launch config. The names of the auto-detected tasks provided by the C/C++ extension can be found in the list that shows up when selecting a debug/launch configuration. It'll look something like "C/C++: <compiler-executable-name> build active file". Ex. "C/C++: g++-13 build active file".
Also note that you can define tasks at a user-level (see How to create a global tasks in VS Code? (user task)). If you always use the same one for quick testing of small files, you can just define it once as a user-level task.

I don't see run button at the top right of the workbench in newly opened folder with single main.cpp file. I just see run button at the bottom of window that has label Select and start debug configuration, but it just generates launch.json with two lines

@vico do you have main.cpp file open, and its editor tab focused?

Yes, main.cpp is opened and is focused
